# Compiler says object is const, I can't see how

Tags: c++, constants

I'm having trouble with this code:

```
NonCommutativePolynomial<SR> differential_at_wrt_variable
  (std::map<VarId,SR> valuation, VarId variable) {

    NonCommutativePolynomial<SR> result;

    for(auto &monomial : monomials_) {
        result += monomial.first.differential_at_wrt_variable(valuation, variable)
                  * monomial.second;
    }

    return result;
}
```

`monomials_` has the type `std::map<NonCommutativeMonomial<SR>,std::uint_fast16_t>`.

In the line `result += ...` I'm getting this compiler error:

> error: passing ‘const NonCommutativeMonomial’ as ‘this’
>   argument of ‘NonCommutativeMonomial
>   NonCommutativeMonomial::differential_at_wrt_variable(std::map&, VarId&) [with SR = LossySemiring]’ discards qualifiers
>   [-fpermissive]

Now I realize that this means that I am calling a method (function?) on a constant object where the method does not guarantee that it won't modify the object. What I don't understand is how `monomial.first` can be constant when I haven't declared it to be thus anywhere. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

EDIT:
See the answers below why `monomial.first` is constant. I need a non-constant copy of it, the class `NonCommutativeMonomial<SR>`has this copy constructor:

```
NonCommutativeMonomial(const NonCommutativeMonomial &m) = default;
```

However, when I call that using

```
NonCommutativeMonomial * mono = new NonCommutativeMonomial<SR>(monomial.first);
```

and work with `mono` afterwards, I still get the same error.

Comment: Does NonCommutativeMonomial extend a base class?

Comment: @Owen: No, it's its own base class. I also forgot to mention that the member `monomials_` has no modifiers except for `private`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In std::map keys are constant objects and you must never change them.

EDIT:

I'd suggest the following change:

```
NonCommutativePolynomial<SR> result;

for(auto &monomial : monomials_) {
    NonCommutativePolynomial<SR> tmp(monomial.first);
    result += tmp.differential_at_wrt_variable(valuation, variable)
              * monomial.second;
}
```

Comment: That should explain it. Can I call a copy constructor on a constant object? That would be the only workaround I can think of to solve this problem, because if I don't want to make major changes, I need `monomial.first` not to be constant.

Comment: @G.Bach: You can not change the state of `monomial.first`. Likely what you want here is to make `NonCommutativeMonomial::differential_at_wrt_variable()` a [const member function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ke686zh(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @sharth: That's just the first call in a call hierarchy where all called member functions would have to be changed to `const`; it's not really an option, I'm afraid.

Comment: @G.Bach yes, it works if you have already an implicitly defined copy constructor or a copy constructor which accepts const Type& parameter.

Comment: I added an example in the answer.

Comment: It still gives me the same error - I'll give up for today and check with the person responsible for that project tomorrow. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

it seems that member function differential_at_wrt_variable has no qualifier const while monomial.first is a const object.
Value type is defined for std::map as

```
typedef pair<const Key, T> value_type;
```

that is Key has qualifier const.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be my problem. I don't understand how `monomial.first` can be `const` if it wasn't declared to be `const` anywhere.

Comment: Ah yes, that explains it. Do you have any ideas how I can get a non-constant copy of a key? Will a simple call to a copy constructor work/be enough?

Comment: I think it wiil be enough to create a temporal object and then apply the function but I thisnk that the design in whole is not very good.

Comment: I agree, that's a design flaw; but I'm only in on this project for a comparatively short time and don't really have the authority to change anything, so it's not my job to fix it :) - Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

The `value_type` of a `std::map<KeyType, MappedType>` is declared as a `std::pair<const KeyType, MappedType>`.

An iterator for a `std::map` (which is what your for loop is using) is over the map's `value_type`.

In your case this results in `monomial.first` having the type `const NonCommutativeMonomial<SR>` which, as you recognise, cannot be used with a non-const member function.

The reason for the key in the value type being `const` is to prevent the map *keys* themselves being modified during the iteration.